# Preserving a ID when editing a record in Database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am trying to edit a Team in my Database, I get all the relevant information, but when I click "OK" all of the variable are reset, which is the expected behavior, but I need to preserve the ID in order to insure I commit the Edit. I was wondering if anyone knew how to do that, I have googled using all kinds of search terms and it all comes up with MVC which I am not using.

Relevant code below.

```
Public Class 
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private f_conAdministrator As OleDb.OleDbConnection ' Import System.Data.OleDB

' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Form Variables
' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private f_blnResult As Boolean      ' Don't use DialogResult since it triggers a cascade close
Private f_intTeamID As Integer

' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Name: Page_Load
' Abstract: Handles the Page load event
' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try

        Dim blnResult As Boolean = False

        ' First time the page is loaded?
        If Page.IsPostBack = False Then

            ' Load the exiting Team data
            blnResult = LoadTeam()

            ' Did it work?
            If blnResult = False Then

                ' No, warn the user ...
                SendMessageToClient("Unable to load team information from the database\n" & "The form will now close.")

                ' Close the form

                ' False = don't generate exception.  This is a planned redirect.
                Response.Redirect("./WManageTeams.aspx", False)

            End If

        End If

    Catch excError As Exception

        ' Log and display error message
        WriteLog(excError)

    End Try

End Sub



' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Name: LoadTeam
' Abstract: Get the team information from the database and populate the
'           form field with it
' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function LoadTeam() As Boolean

    Dim blnResult As Boolean = False

    Try

        Dim udtTeam As udtTeamType = New udtTeamType

        ' Which team do we edit?
        f_intTeamID = Val(Request.QueryString("intTeamID"))
        udtTeam.intTeamID = f_intTeamID

        ' Open DB connection
        If OpenDatabaseConnectionMSAccess() = True Then

            ' Do it
            blnResult = GetTeamInformationFromDatabase(udtTeam)

            ' Did it work?
            If blnResult = True Then

                ' Yes
                txtTeam.Text = udtTeam.strTeam
                txtMascot.Text = udtTeam.strMascot

                ' Set focus to Team name and select existing text
                txtTeam.Focus()

            End If

            ' Close the conection
            CloseDatabaseConnection()

        End If

    Catch excError As Exception

        ' Log and display error message
        WriteLog(excError)

    End Try

    Return blnResult

End Function



' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Name: btnOK_Click
' Abstract: If the data is good then save the changes
' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click

    Try

        ' Is the data OK?
        If IsValidData() = True Then

            ' Open a connection
            If OpenDatabaseConnectionMSAccess() = True Then

                ' Yes, save
                If SaveData() = True Then

                    ' If the save was successful then ...

                    ' Success
                    f_blnResult = True

                End If

                ' Close the Connection
                CloseDatabaseConnection()

            End If

            ' Did it work?
            If f_blnResult = True Then

                ' Yes, redirect.  False = don't generate exception.  This is a planned redirect.
                Response.Redirect("./WManageTeams.aspx?intTeamID=" & f_intTeamID, False)

            End If

        End If

    Catch excError As Exception

        ' Log and display error message
        WriteLog(excError)

    End Try

End Sub


' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Name: GetTeamInformationFromDatabase
' Abstract: Get data for the specified team from the database
' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function GetTeamInformationFromDatabase(ByRef udtTeam As udtTeamType) As Boolean

    Dim blnResult As Boolean = False

    Try

        Dim strSelect As String = ""
        Dim cmdSelect As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim drTTeams As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

        ' Build the select string
        strSelect = "SELECT *" & _
                    " FROM TTeams" & _
                    " WHERE intTeamID = " & udtTeam.intTeamID

        ' Retrieve the record
        cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, f_conAdministrator)
        drTTeams = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

        ' Read (there should be 1 and only 1 row)
        drTTeams.Read()
        With drTTeams
            udtTeam.strTeam = .Item("strTeam")
            udtTeam.strMascot = .Item("strMascot")
        End With

        ' Clean up
        drTTeams.Close()

        ' Success
        blnResult = True

    Catch excError As Exception

        ' Log and display error message
        WriteLog(excError)

    End Try

    Return blnResult

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preserve it in session variable like below:-

```
f_intTeamID = Val(Request.QueryString("intTeamID"))
Session("f_intTeamID") = f_intTeamID
```

Next time when the page is post back then retrieve it from session.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thank you. Hopefully this post helps somebody else in the future. Saved me probably 10hours of dead ends until I found it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As in the first request when you load the data, you can also read the ID from the request parameters in the PostBack request:

```
f_intTeamID = Val(Request.QueryString("intTeamID"))
```

The instance that serves a request is only created for the specific request and thrown away afterwards. When the new request arrives at the server after the user has clicked the `OK` button a new instance is created. This is why the values of the variables are gone.

As you might need the ID in every request, you can add the statements to the Page_Load method so that the variable is set whenever you need it.

Comment: your saying just simply move    f_intTeamID = Val(Request.QueryString("intTeamID")) to my page_load procedure?

Comment: @AdamSchneider: yes, that should do it. It should be one of the first lines.

Comment: Should i put it outside my Try block?

Comment: Markus, that didn't work f_intTeamID still resets to Zero.

Comment: @AdamSchneider: maybe better inside, as the conversion might fail if someone calls the page with a non-integer id. In front of the `If Page.IsPostBack = False Then`

Comment: @AdamSchneider It is ok if it is reset; but after the value of the request parameter is assigned to the value, it should be there again.